# Why can't I pass void and a parameter to the function in C?

Tags: c, function, void, return-type

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun();

int main(void) {
  fun(fun());
  return 0;
}

void fun()
{
  printf("function is called");
}
```

The return type of function fun is void. So the below statement should be valid right!

```
fun(fun())
```

But the compiler raises compilation error as *error: argument type 'void' is incomplete*. Cannot understand what the error means?

Comment: As you say `fun()` is a `void` function, and therefore its return value cannot be passed to itself (there isn't one).

Comment: Also the `fun` function takes no arguments, therefore you cannot call it with an argument.

Comment: @Jabberwocky are you sure? I thought that was the weakness of the obsolete function definition `void fun()`.

Comment: try declaring as `void fun(void);` for more errors...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `int fun(int);` ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If I declare the function as ```void fun(void)```. It shows "too many arguments to function call, expected 0,have 1". Because calling the function fun as argument to itself.

Comment: yeah. Question doesn't make much sense. What is the purpose of this code? XY problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you're right

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am trying to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: Perhaps the fault is more obvious when you try `printf("%d", fun());`. What value should be printed, when `void fun()` does not return a value? You can't pass the return value from a `void` function to another function, because there *isn't one*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int arg);   // function takes one argument

int main(void) {
  fun(fun(1));      // use one argument when calling fun
  return 0;
}

int fun(int arg)
{
  printf("function is called\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understood what you said. But my question is why declaring the function return type as void raises an error.

Comment: If your `fun` function "returns" `void` you cannot use is as a function argument, just as you cannot write `int value = fun(2)`.